# Move thumbnails overflowing into another container

Tags: jquery

Ok say I have 10 thumbnail images and I have a container that has fixed height but a elastic width. Is there a way to move all the thumbnails overflowing in that div into a newly created div wrapper?

The reason I want all overflowing thumbnails in another wrapper is because I want to implement these wrappers into a carosel so all overflowing thumbnails can be found by clicking on the next button on the carosel.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" class="thumb" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
</div>
```

The thing is because this is a responsive design I also need this to work as the window is resized. So if the user reduces the width of the window less thumbnails will appear in the first wrapper container and as the width container increases more thumbnails will appear in the first wrapper.

I thought there would be a plugin somewhere around for this but I have not come across anything.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

---

Ive managed to get it to work on page load but I have a problem when the window is resized. I'm using JRespond to trigger the wrap_thumbs function on specific window widths. It seems that the function may be triggered many times causing the browser to basically crash.

Download link:
[project_ZIP](http://dev.imagine-that.co.uk/thumb_wrap.zip)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I don't like the thought of shuffling overflow into another container. Sounds nightmarish. You should be able to manage everything within one container.

Comment: Beetroot: As already mentioned the point of me wanting to do this is so that overflowing content falls into the next page of the carosel.

Asad: I am aproaching the problem in a new way because all my previous methods were hopeless. I am currently trying to work on something.

Comment: I added my attempt to solve the issue please take a look.